# Duda sobre sobre instanciar un objeto que posee areglos de n elementos en el main

Tags: java, array, programación-bajo-nivel

Mi pregunta es sobre un proyecto que me dejaron en un curso de java básico, el proyecto consiste en un prgrama que cree empresas y que esta a se vez posean un jefe y un numero n de administradores.
Mi duda viene en como instanciar en el main el objeto de empresa ya que este aparte de poseer las variables primitivas como el nombre,fecha, dinero,etc posee un objeto de la clase "Jefe" y un arreglo de objetos de la clase "Administrador"
Mi duda viene en como debo de instanciar el objeto en el main cuando el usuario decida crear una empresa. Tengo esto de código en el main pero no se como pueda hacer para que se cree el arreglo en la clase empresa con la dimensión que el usuario desee

```
  public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Que desa hacer): \n 1=Agregar impresa \n 2= Listar empresas \n 4=Acceder al menu de una empresa 5=Salir");
  int opcion=sc.nextInt();

  if(opcion==1){
    Empresa empresa= new Empresa();
    empresa.crear();
  }
```

En el codigo de empresa tengo esto

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Empresa{
  Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner sci=new Scanner(System.in);
  String nombreEm;
  int anio;
  String sector;
  double capital;
  Jefe jf;
  Administrador arreglo1[];

  public Empresa(){

  }


  public Empresa(String nombreEm,int anio,String sector,double capital,Jefe jf,Administrador arreglo1[]){
    this.nombreEm=nombreEm;
    this.anio=anio;
    this.sector=sector;
    this.capital=capital;
    this.jf=jf;
    this.arreglo1=arreglo1;
  }

  public void crear(){
    System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre de la empresa: ");
    nombreEm= sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingresa el anio de creacion de la empresa: ");
    anio=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingresa el sector de la empresa: ");
    sector=sci.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingresa el capital con el que cuenta la empresa: ");
    capital=sc.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Inserta los datos del jefe:");
    jf.introducir();
    System.out.println("Cuantos administradores tiene la empresa");
    int ad=sc.nextInt();
    Administrador[] arreglo1= new Administrador[ad];
    System.out.println("Introduce los datos de los administradores");
    for (int i=0;i<ad ;i++ ) {
      System.out.println("Datos del administrador "+(i+1)+":");
      arreglo1[i].introducir();
    }
```

El codigo de la clase Administrador es el siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Administrador extends Empleado{
  Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

  public Administrador(){

  }

  public Administrador(String nombre, int edad, float salario,float dinero,String noCuenta,String contrasena,float impuestos,String tipo, String empresa){
    super(nombre,edad,salario,dinero,noCuenta,contrasena,impuestos,tipo,empresa);
  }

  void introducir(){
    System.out.println("Nombre del Administrador de la empresa:");
    this.nombre= sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Edad del administrador:");
    this.edad=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Salario del administrador:");
    this.salario=sc.nextLong();
    System.out.println("Dinero del administrador al iniciar su trabajo:");
    this.dinero=sc.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Introduce el numero de cuenta que tendrá el administrador:");
    this.noCuenta=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Introduce la contrasena que tendra el administrador:");
    this.contrasena=sc.nextLine();
    this.tipo= "Administrador";
}
```

}
Al ejecutar el código después de introducir el numero de administradores que voy a querer me vota la siguiente excepcion:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Empresa.crear(Empresa.java:45)
        at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Cabe aclarar que solo se pueden usar los temas de java basico que llegan hasta el concepto de polimorfismo y arreglos multidimensionales.
Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que inicializar el array de administradores de la siguiente forma:

```
 public void crear(){
    System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre de la empresa: ");
    nombreEm= sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingresa el anio de creacion de la empresa: ");
    anio=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingresa el sector de la empresa: ");
    sector=sci.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingresa el capital con el que cuenta la empresa: ");
    capital=sc.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Cuantos administradores tiene la empresa");
    int ad=sc.nextInt();
    arreglo1= new Administrador[ad];
    for(int i = 0; i < ad; i++){
        arreglo1[i] = new Administrador();
    }
    System.out.println("Introduce los datos de los administradores");
    for (int i=0;i<ad ;i++ ) {
      System.out.println("Datos del administrador "+(i+1)+":");
      arreglo1[i].introducir();
    }
  }
```

Puedes encontrar algo confuso entender por que no funcionaba lo tuyo cuando estas empezando.
Me explico. Lo que estabas haciendo es definir un array de administradores en memoria con un tamaño de "ad", pero **solamente estas reservando el espacio en memoria**. En cada dirección que forma el array tienes una referencia que apunta a null, ya que no existe un objeto de administradores (**Porque no lo has instanciado**).

```
for(int i = 0; i < ad; i++){
   arreglo1[i] = new Administrador();
}
```

De esta forma lo que haces, es asignar a cada dirección del array un objeto de administradores. Des esta forma solucionas el problema. Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono perfectamente tu explicacion!!

Comment: Me alegro. Márcala como correcta y así podemos dejar la pregunta cerrada.